# Find ProcessID - pidof not working

Tags: debian, pidof

I need to try and find the ProcessId of a process.

Initially I was doing:

```
application="/home/user/apps/appName.app"
appPid=$(pidof -x $application)
```

This worked fine.

However, it now turns out that the applictaion could run from a variety of locations, such as:

```
/home/user/apps/appName.app
/home/user/desktop/appName.app
/home/user/desktop/link to apps/appName.app
```

So I tried to simply do

```
application="appName.app"
appPid=$(pidof -x $application)
```

But this didn't find any matches. I assume that `pidof` requires a full path to match.

How else can I get the ProcessId?

---

I think I need to further explain.

If I do

```
ps aux | grep application.app
```

I get two results.

```
user 29912 . . . . /home/user/apps/application.app
user 12345 . . . . grep application.app
```

If I then do

```
var1=`pgrep application.app`
echo $var1
```

the result is blank. It should be 29912.

Comment: What if you do `pgrep -f application.app`?

Comment: That looks like it works. cheers

Answer (score 2):

The pgrep itself returns the process ids. Use:

```
     $pgrep <process_name>


     $pgrep bash
     3896
     4013
     4115
```

If you want the output to store in variable:

```
   var1=`pgrep <appname>`


  pids=`pgrep bash`
  echo $pids
  3896 4013 4115
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following:

```
appPid=$(pgrep $application)
```